# Where do I find the full man page for afplay

Tags: command-line, unix

In Terminal `afplay -h` shows full help text but the man page shows hardly nothing.

Is there any way to get a longer help page for `man afplay`?

---

I never use Terminal and it would be much easier if i could see this longer complete man page in Man Viewer or if there would be some kind of AppleScript or unix script which reads it from somewhere and then shows it or re-writes the man page.

Some other unix apps has this problem too and it would be nice if it works for all apps with short man page.

I wanted to use afplay long time ago, but when i saw its short man page i didn't start to use it because i didn't know it has all those settings which are listed in Terminal.

Comment: What is exactly  your question. You get the help with your first command where is the problem ?

Answer (score 2):

No `afplay` comes with a short (incomplete) man page.

You could open a bug report request but I doubt it will taken into consideration or you could use the content of the `afplay -h` to [re-write the man page](http://www.schweikhardt.net/man_page_howto.html).

Answer (score 2):

https://www.unix.com/os-x-apple-/267933-osx-afplay-command-line-audio-player-_manual_.html has more detail than actual (lame) manpage.

I found the following useful:

> `-v` is a floating point value between 0.0, volume minimum, and 1.0, volume maximum.
>   This is NOT a linear scaling but relative to a logarithmic output volume level, so do NOT assume a value 0.5 is literally half volume.
>
> `-t` is an integer OR floating point value of arbitrary length inside the full playing time ofthe file to be played. Value 0.0 is the same as not have having the -t flag in the command, in other words it becomes disabled.

Comment: `strings \`which afplay\`` dumps a bunch of strings from the program including the help data found at that link.